# How to set the aging interval and # of days for AP Aging Summary

Tags: report, qbxml

I don't see how to specify an interval in the Desktop SDK for AgingReportQueryRq AgingReportType of APAgingSummary.  It defaults to 30 day intervals and 90 limit.  I don't want those.  I can see how to change them in the UI, but I need to generate the report using the SDK

Thanks.

Comment: please add to the question what you're trying now.

Answer (score 0):

Use ReportPeriod or ReportDateMacro to pick the days you want.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK does not offer access to set the Interval or Through fields like you can in the  QuickBooks UI.

You should be able to generate the data and create your own report. I would suggest running an Open Invoices report. You can specify to have the open balance as of report end date or as of today.

```
    IGeneralDetailReportQuery rpt = MsgRequest.AppendGeneralDetailReportQueryRq();
    rpt.GeneralDetailReportType.SetValue(ENGeneralDetailReportType.gdrtOpenInvoices);
    rpt.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icDate);
    rpt.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icDueDate);
    rpt.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icName);
    rpt.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icOpenBalance);
    rpt.ReportOpenBalanceAsOf.SetValue(ENReportOpenBalanceAsOf.robaoReportEndDate);
    rpt.ORReportPeriod.ReportPeriod.FromReportDate(/* FROM REPORT DATE */);
    rpt.ORReportPeriod.ReportPeriod.ToReportDate(/* TO REPORT DATE */);
```